# How to append a trailing slash to URL using htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect from `author/$username` to `author/$username/`.
The `$username` is the author's *username*.

This is my `.htaccess` content :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^author/([A-Za-z0-9-\+]+)/?$ author/index.php?username=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^authorpost/([A-Za-z0-9-\+]+)/postid/([0-9]+)/?$ author/index.php?username=$1&postid=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

How do I need to change it?

Comment: *I wanna redirect from author/$username to author/$uesrname/\** ... ummm, presumably that's a typo (`$uesrname`) and you're just trying to trim everything after the username in an URL?

Comment: right,i want to add something after that URL and  need to using / after that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly you just need to append a slash to the URL `/author/<username>`?

Try something like this at the top of the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^(author/[A-Za-z0-9+-]+)$ /$1/ [R=302,L]
```

The `+` inside a character class has no special meaning so does not need to be escaped. The hyphen (`-`) should be at the start or end of the character class in order to match a literal hyphen (without having to escape it).

In the following rewrite, you can now enforce the trailing slash, instead of making it optional. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^author/([A-Za-z0-9+-]+)/$ author/index.php?username=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

#### Summary

```
RewriteEngine On

# Append trailing slash if omitted
RewriteRule ^(author/[A-Za-z0-9+-]+)$ /$1/ [NC,R=302,L]

# Internal rewrites...
RewriteRule ^author/([A-Za-z0-9+-]+)/$ author/index.php?username=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^authorpost/([A-Za-z0-9+-]+)/postid/([0-9]+)/?$ author/index.php?username=$1&postid=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Ideally, you should avoid using the `NC` flag on the *internal rewrites* in order to avoid potentially duplicate content. At the very least, it should be unnecessary.